# C++ substr usage return error

Tags: c++

### First Question

I tried to do the following

```
myfile.open("file.txt");
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
getline(myfile,sline);
delimiter = sline.substr(2,1);
    }

cout << "Delimiter is " << delimiter << endl;
```

My file.txt is something like this

```
AD#Andorra#AN#AD#AND#20.00#Andorra la Vella#Europe#Euro#EUR#67627.00
AE#United Arab Emirates#AE#AE#ARE#784.00#Abu Dhabi#Middle East#UAE Dirham#AED#2407460.00
```

It return me an error code on runtime

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I want to get the value # as my delimiter,

### Second Question

My .h file got this declaration

```
#define LINE_DATA_DELIMITER     ","
```

Can i re-define LINE_DATA_DELIMITER as "#" , and instead of using "#" , can i define using the value of variable delimiter.

Update: Question 1 is solved.. I need help on Second Question Thanks!

Comment: what should i use to just read the first line, and get the value

Comment: You don't check if `getline` succeeded before you use the value it returned!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because you run the loop one time too many. The `eof` condition happens only *after* one read has already failed.

Try this instead

```
myfile.open("file.txt");
while(getline(myfile,sline))
{ 
   delimiter = sline.substr(2,1);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my Question One.
I need further help on question 2, thank you.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking in the second question. Perhaps you should follow the "one question per question" principle of StackOverflow, and ask this as a new question with some example code?

Answer (score 0):

I read this in the substr doc http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/.

"If the position passed is past the end of the string, an out_of_range exception is thrown."
I think it's because in sline.substr(2,1) you inverted the range.